# Shared Service in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a button which triggers a custom modal (I used the modal from here http://codepen.io/m-e-conroy/pen/ALsdF)

The button resides in `MainController` controller.

## MainController

```
app.controller('MainController', function($scope, sharedService) {
    $dialogs.create('dialog.html', 'SecondController',
        {}, {key: false, back: 'static'});
    
    // Start broadcast
    sharedService.prepForBroadcast('Hello AngularJS');
});
```

## SecondController

```
app.controller('SecondController', function($scope, sharedService) {
    // This piece of code doesn't get called.
    $scope.$on('handleBroadcast', function() {
        console.log('received broadcast');
    });
});
```

## sharedService

```
app.factory('sharedService', function($rootScope) {
    var data = {message: ''};

    data.prepForBroadcast = function(message) {
        this.message = message;
        $rootScope.$broadcast('handleBroadcast');
    };

    return data;
});
```

My question is: In `SecondController`, why it does not listen to the broadcast? Why that piece of code (commented in `SecondController` above) would never get executed?

Answer (score 1):

In second controller use **$rootScope.on** not **$scope.on**.

Service is changing rootscope not the second controller scope.

Answer (score 0):

I just did a simple set up of your example, everything seems to work, so must be something else in your code.

Working example using your code:
http://jsbin.com/rosutoya/2/edit

Is it possible you're not seeing what you expect because your page doesn't actually have 2 controllers running?